# How do I get from $\frac{1}{(1+10\%)^1}+\frac{1}{(1+10\%)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+10\%)^{5}}$ to $\frac{1-(1+10\%)^{-5}}{10\%}$?

Tags: finance, geometric-progressions

I'm currently studying a finance textbook and they just give me the transformation from the sum to the simplification.

They say it's a geometric progression but they don't show the demonstration.

Could you please give me all the steps with all the details to go from
from $$
Present Value = 
26.4
\times
\left[
\frac{1}{(1+10\%)^1}
+
\frac{1}{(1+10\%)^2}
+
...
+
\frac{1}{(1+10\%)^5}
\right]
=100
$$

to

$$
Present Value = 
26.4
\times
\frac{1-(1+10\%)^{-5}}{10\%}
=100
$$ 
?

Comment: Use the identity $a+a^2+\dots+a^n=a(1+a+a^2+\dots a^{n-1})=a (1-a^n)/(1-a)\,$ for $a=1/1.1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that
$$
\frac{1}{(1+10\%)^{n}} = \left(\frac{1}{1+10\%}\right)^{n}
$$

Suppose we have 
$$a = \frac{1}{1+10\%}=\frac{1}{1.1}$$
and
$$S=a+a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5$$ 
Then multiply by $a$ 
$$a\times S=a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5+a^6$$
Subtract the second from the first to obtain 
$$
1\times S - a\times S
= (1-a)\times S
=a-a^6
=a \times 1 -a\times a^5
=a\times (1-a^5)$$ 
(the point is that most terms simply cancel) so that $$S=\frac a{1-a}(1-a^5)$$

Then you put 
$
a=\frac 1{1.1}
$

Finally
$$
S=\frac{1}{10\%}\times (1-(1+10\%)^{5^{-1}}))
\\
S=\frac{1-(1+10\%)^{-5}}{10\%}
$$

More generally, for an interest rate $r$, $a=\frac 1{1+r}$, whence $$S=\frac 1r\left(1-\frac 1{(1+r)^5}\right)$$